# Can’t login to MySQL/mariaDB - [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) (get_data.php)

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I am moving a stable Appache2/PHP/MysQL web service to a new machine and I have come across a problem which I am unable to resolve despite hours of searchng on the internet.  The old machine is Debian Weezy, the new machine is Debian Stretch.  Javascript running on the client calls a PHP script running on the server.  The PHP script should loggon to MySQL/mariaDB and retrieve the data which is returned to the client as a JSON string.  This has been working ok (with old MySQL) for the past four years.  But on the new machine I have encountered a problem logging onto the MySQL/mariaDB.  I have created a number of user accounts on Mysql/mariadb with different hostnames with no success.  All of the accounts work if the PHP script is run locally via the command line, none work via the web client.  If I replace all the code in the PHP script with just example data to be returned everything works from the client as expected.  e.g.

```
<?PHP
      echo ‘{“k1”:”3.0”,”k2”:”4.2”,”k3”:”2.6”,”k4”:”1.9”}’;
?>
```

The error is caused by the Mysql login failure. I feel sure the answer is a simple one but I just can’t find it.  Abbreviated code snippet follows:-

```
 <?PHP
   $link = mysqli_connect(‘hostname’, ‘user’, ‘password’, ‘database’);
   if(!$link) {
       printf("Connection failed: %s\n");
       exit();
   }
   if($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM my_data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")) {
       $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
       $php_array = array('k1' => $row[“data0”],
                          'k2' => $row[“data1”],
                          'k3' => $row[“data2”],
                          'k4’ => $row["ldata3”]
       );
       echo json_encode($php_array);   // this returns the data
       mysqli_free_result($result);
       mysqli_close($link);  
   }
 ?>
```

I have tried hostname = ‘’, ‘%’ and ‘localhost’ - the old machine uses ‘localhost’.

all users have ALL PRIVILEGES on ‘database’.

Perhaps it is some OS permissions issue?

Many thanks

Comment: Now try __normal__ quotes `'` and `"` instead of what you have.

Comment: Please read the displayed quotes characters as ‘normal’ quote characters ' & "  - Those shown in the code example are an unfortunate byproduct of ‘cut and paste’ which went unnoticed - sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED - PHP7.0 and associated modules for Apache2 and MySQL no longer support mysqli-connect().  The solution was to delete all PHP7 replace it with PHP5.